How to get attachment content from chat message using graph api
Given that:

gc is a GraphServiceClient with all required delegated rights set,
ContentUrl of attachment looks like: https://somedomain-my.sharepoint.com/personal/firstname_lastname_some-domain_com/Documents/Fichiers%20de%20conversation%20Microsoft%20Teams/hello.txt

I use the following code consisting of sequentially retrieve:

Site, then
Drive, then
Drive Item, finally
the content

That is 4 queries.
Is there a shortest way ?
int cptMess = 0;
foreach (var mes in mess) {
    cptMess++;
    int cptFile = cptMess * 1000;
    foreach (var a in mes.Attachments) {
        cptFile++;
        // NOT WORKING
        //var test = await gc.Shares[a.ContentUrl].DriveItem.GetAsync();
        //if ( test != null ) {
        //    Console.WriteLine(test.Id);
        //}
                            
        var uParts = ExtractSharePointUrlParts(a.ContentUrl);

        IDictionary<string, object> rps = new Dictionary<string, object> {
            {"host", uParts.Domain} ,
            { "path", uParts.SitePath}
            
        };
        var ri = new Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.RequestInformation {
            HttpMethod = Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Method.GET,
            UrlTemplate = gc.RequestAdapter.BaseUrl + "/sites/{host}:{path}",
            QueryParameters = rps
        };

        Site site = await gc.RequestAdapter.SendAsync<Site>(
            ri,
            Site.CreateFromDiscriminatorValue
        );

        if ( site == null ) {
            continue;
        }                    

        DriveCollectionResponse dcr = await gc.Sites[site.Id].Drives.GetAsync();

        if ( dcr == null) {
            continue;
        }

        Drive drive = null;

        foreach(var d in dcr.Value) {
            if ( a.ContentUrl.StartsWith(d.WebUrl) ) {
                drive = d;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( drive == null ) {
            continue;
        }        

        string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uParts.FilePath);
        var files = await gc.Drives[drive.Id].Items.GetAsync((p) => {                            
            p.QueryParameters.Filter = $"name eq '{fn}'";
        });

        if ( files == null ) {
            continue;
        }

        DriveItem di = null;
        
        foreach(var item in files.Value) {
            if ( item.WebUrl == a.ContentUrl ) {
                di = item;
                break;
            }
        }
                        
        if ( di == null ) {
            continue;
        }

        Stream? fs = await gc.Drives[drive.Id].Items[di.Id].Content.GetAsync();
        if ( fs != null ) {
            using Stream ds = System.IO.File.Create(
                $@"c:\temp\attachment{cptFile:0000}{System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fn)}");
            await fs.CopyToAsync(ds);
        }                                        
    }
}

static (string Domain, string SitePath, string DocumentLibrary, 
    string FilePath) ExtractSharePointUrlParts(string url
) {    

    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    string domain = uri.Host;
    string fullPath = uri.AbsolutePath;
    string[] pathParts = fullPath.Split(new[] { '/' },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string sitePath = $"/{pathParts[0]}/{pathParts[1]}";
    string documentLibrary = pathParts[2];
    string filePath = string.Join("/", pathParts, 3, pathParts.Length - 3);
    filePath = Uri.UnescapeDataString(filePath);

    return (domain, sitePath, documentLibrary, filePath);
}

